# How do I get children of the a parent element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

How can I get the children of a parent element?

I tried like this:
`(block.Parent as FrameworkElement).Children` but there is no `Children` property for `FrameworkElement`s

Comment: It depends of what type your parent-object has. If it's something like Stackpanel you can check the Children-Property. Some Elements do not have Child-Elemenst like a TextBlock. A Button for example has a Content-Property, which can be anything (for examle a Stackpanel)

Comment: @Tomtom the thing is that the parent can be of any kind..

Comment: If there is more than one child, it's probably a `Panel`. So try casting the Parent to a Panel instead of FrameworkElement.

Comment: @FlorianGl it's not always a panel..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` method of [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild.aspx)

```
for(var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildCount(element); i++)
{
   var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
   ...
}
```

An example is also available on that page.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I add to those children? (add element to the parent of another element?)

Comment: You can only add if it's a panel, otherwise you have to replace the child.

Comment: @FlorianGl and how can I replace the child?

Comment: `((ContentControl)object).Content = newContent;`

Comment: @FlorianGl the object should the the child or the parent? and what is the content? (can I replace a textblock with a grid?)

Comment: The object is the Control where you want to replace the Content, yes you can set every object as Content and it doesnt matter what has been there before.

Comment: @FlorianGl can you please give me an example of replacing a textblock with a grid? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a some `Panel` as a container for child elements. So you need to cast to a `Panel.

```
(block.Parent as Panel).Children
```